# How to remove all widgets from a fragment on onResume

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, widget

I have a fragment that contains many buttons that were added to the layout dynamically. Because they were added dynamically I didn't assign them ID's to reference them.

In my main activity's onResume, I want to be able to just clear all widgets in this certain fragment without needing to reference each button by ID to remove it. Is there a way I can do this?

Possibly running the following command but applied to all Buttons without referencing particular ID's:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**EDIT:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < R.layout.grid_cell.getCount(); i++) {
View v = R.layout.grid_cell.getChildAt(i);
R.layout.grid_cell.removeView(v);
// or you can check the view
//if (v instanceof Button) {
//    layout.removeView(v);
//}
}
```

Comment: Will adding them to an array list and create a simple loop do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

in your onResume()

```
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        layout.removeView(v);
      // or you can check the view
      //if (v instanceof Button) {
      //    layout.removeView(v);
      //}
    }
```

**Edit**
 "layout" is not layout file.

```
RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
```

If you're using RecyclerView you must return View of each row item. For example if you want remove views in onResume(), you can return the view like your own itemClickListener into activity. As the result the View is your row's root View. And than you can get view.getChildCount() and put it into loop. It doesn't matter GridLayout or others. The think is same.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply!! (I've made an EDIT ABOVE IN the QUESTION). What do I use for "layout"? I'm using a ReclyerView and GridLayout to place my dynamic buttons. Right now it cannot resolve any method that I use on "R.layout.grid_cell" where grid_cell is where I am storing my button view for using in the gridlayout